# A question about Sobolev functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, bounded and smooth. Let $\lambda_j$ and $e_j$, $j\in\mathbb{N}$, be the eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ with zero Dirichlet boundary data on $\partial\Omega$. We suppose that: $|| e_j ||_{L^2(\Omega)}=1$. Let $s\in(0,1)$. Let $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, i want to prove that:
$$ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\lambda_j^s<+\infty, $$
where:
$$(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega e_ju\,dx. $$
I have no idea to go on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* What are the coefficients if you express $u$ in terms of the basis of eigenfunctions?

Comment: The coefficients are $(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}$?